# a question about Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem

Tags: probability, analysis

I (a beginner in probability) have some confusions arising from problem 36.7 of the book "probability and measure" by Billingsley. It says that there is on the unit
interval with Lebesgue measure no process $[X_t,t > 0]$ for which the $X_t$ are
independent and assume the values 0 and 1 with probability 1/2 each (a sketch of the proof is in the notes of the problems in the book). However, suppose we are in the usual infinite product setting, i.e., a product of measure space $\Pi_{t>0} (S_t, \Sigma_t, \mu_t)$, $S_t=\{0,1\}, \Sigma_t=\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \mu_t(\{0\})=\mu_t(\{1\})=1/2$ for all $t$, then $\mu_{t_1...t_k}(E_{t_1}\times ...\times E_{t_k})=\mu_{t_1}(E_{t_1})\times...\times \mu_{t_k}(E_{t_k}), E_{t_i}\in \Sigma_{t_i}$ gives a consistent system of measures, then Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem gives us a process $[X_t,t > 0]$ having $\mu_{t_1...t_k}$ as its finite dimensional distributions and I checked that it is independent and assume values 0 and 1 with probility 1/2. But we know from the above exercise that such a process does not exists. I want to know what went wrong with the existence argument. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the answer must lie in Billingsley's definition of "process".  For example, does he require that it be jointly measurable (i.e. the map $\Omega \times [0,1] \ni (\omega, t) \to X_t(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$ is measurable)?  I have a feeling this may be hard to satisfy.

Comment: Anyway, have you looked at the sketch of the solution?  It may make it clear why your counterexample isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cardinalities of the measure spaces are different.  An interval in $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$, whereas the other measure space you construct has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

It is possible to construct a sequence $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$, with $X_n$ being independent and $\Pr(X_n = \pm 1) = 1/2$, on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, that is what the solution of this problem says. But my confusion is when we can apply Kolmogorov existence theorem because the only assumption in the theorem is the system of finite measures being consistent, and under no assumptions on the product space there exists a measure on the product space whose restriction to finite products coincide with this system of finite measures, and hence the coordiate process has the given finite distribution. Then the only problem might be the existence of a process from the unit interval to this coordiate process, but I do not see what the problem is.

Comment: The Kolmogorov existence theorem is fine, and such a process does exist.  What is not true is that such a process can exist with $[0,1]$ as the underlying measure space.  You say that you do not see what the problem is, but how can you construct such a map?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I did not see the problem why such a process cannot exist, or why can't we construct a measurable map from the unit interval to the coordiate process.

Comment: More precisely, if we define $f:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}^{R^+}$ such that $Z_t(f(x))=X_t(x)$ where $Z_t$ is projection onto the $t$th coordinate, why can't $f$ be measurable? Measurability does not seem to depend on cardinality.

Comment: How does that define $f$?

Comment: I think they are defined either way: if we have any mapping $f:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}^{R^+}$, then we define a family of mappings $X_t$ by the way above. Conversely, if we have a family of $X_t$, it well defines a mapping $f:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}^{R^+}$. The only concern is measurability because if $f$ is measurable, then it would imply a process on the unit interval exist. But I cannot see how it must be nonmeasurable.

Comment: If you want to construct an example $X_t$, you cannot start by assuming it exists.  Hence you must construct the function $f$.  And no such $f$ can exist because of cardinality.

Comment: ok, now I see the point. My original thought was $f$ does not have to be onto so cardinality does not matter, but if $f$ is not onto, then $X_t$ cannot take value $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Thank you very much! It really helps.

Comment: You are very welcome.  Do I get the points now?  If you click the green check mark, I'll get 15 points.